# Laravel/PHP - Group by key and sum values that have that key

Tags: php, laravel

I have the below collection stored in the variable `$items`:

```php
"items": [
      {
        "qty": "2",
        "tariffCode": "39239000",
        "name": "Item #1",
        "positionTotalPrice": "10"
      },
      {
        "qty": "2",
        "tariffCode": "39239000",
        "name": "Item #2",
        "positionTotalPrice": "10"
      },
      {
        "qty": "2",
        "tariffCode": "80000000",
        "name": "Item #3",
        "positionTotalPrice": "10"
      }
];
```

For this collection, I would like to group the items by the `tariffCode` key, and then accumulate the `qty` and `positionTotalPrice` keys. Further, I want to remove the `name` key as well from the output.

The output should then be:

```php
"items": [
      {
        "qty": "4",
        "tariffCode": "39239000",
        "positionTotalPrice": "20"
      },
      {
        "qty": "2",
        "tariffCode": "80000000",
        "positionTotalPrice": "10"
      }
];
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```php
$items = collect($items)
            ->groupBy('tariffCode')
            ->sum('positionTotalPrice')
            ->sum('qty')
            ->pluck(['positionTotalPrice', 'qty', 'tariffCode']);
```

However, this gives me the error:

> Call to a member function sum() on int

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like the sum method returns an integer, so you can't chain more method calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that you can't use sum() after groupBy(). You have to use the groupBy() and then into a loop, doing the sum() for each group.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-groupby 
This show you what groubBy() return.

Try this instead:

```
$items = collect($items)->groupBy('tariffCode');
$items->toArray();

$groups = new Collection;
foreach($items as $key => $item) {
    $groups->push([
        'tariffCode' => $key,
        'qty' => $item->sum('qty'),
        'positionTotalPrice' => $item->sum('positionTotalPrice')
    ]);
}
```

Comment: This gives me `Trying to use sum on an array`. If I `dd($item)`, it returns:   `0 => array:4 [▼
    "qty" => "10"
    "name" => "Item #1"
    "tariffCode" => "39239000"
    "positionTotalPrice" => "10"
  ]`

Comment: Also, I think on line two - the `toArray` is not doing anything. I added it after the `groupBy()` in line 1.

Comment: Yeah, i tought it was possible. Let me test it. I'll edit, either removing the ```$item->toArray()``` or creating a new Collection of the $item inot the loop while do the job.

Comment: The line ```$item->toArray()``` tell the collection to reorder the key. Without it, at the moment you will use the collection, it will erase what have been done with it.

Comment: This should work properly. I tried it and my result is good on my side. If it's not, send the code that retrieve the items before you use ```$items = collect($items)->groupBy('tariffCode');```

Comment: I had exact same problem. IT WORKED !! Thanks